# Each first element of a pagination/list gets parsed twice on AJAX website - Selenium 3.0.2, Firefox webdriver, BeautifulSoup 4.5.1

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have been encountering for three days a very annoying problem with both Selenium and Bs4 - although I think Selenium is actually guilty (or rather my code).

Anyway, as a hundred people before me, I am trying to parse this website: http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/

I go to the 2007-08 season from the 2015-16 one. First I get to the season webpage, then Selenium helps me navigating through the season's pagination. When done, I jump up to the next season.

What I did for that is parsing each season and get their pagination for each. All the links have then be consolidated into a list. Thus, I have now a big list of around 72 links which I am iterating on.

Sample of the list:

```
tot_links[0:10]
['http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/2/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/3/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/4/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/5/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/6/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/7/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/#/page/8/',
 'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2014-2015/results/',
 u'http://www.oddsportal.com//soccer/france/ligue-1-2014-2015/results/#/page/2/']
```

I use Selenium to manage the website's javascript and then BS4 to collect the cells data. Everything here is fine.

However when I run the loop, I get twice the data for each "main" season webpage (or the page 1 of the pagination). For instance, for the season 2015-2016, I get twice the data within the "team" list elements [0:2]:

```
[u'Angers - Toulouse', u'Caen - Bordeaux', ... ,u'Paris SG - Caen', u'Lyon - Nice']

 [u'Angers - Toulouse', u'Caen - Bordeaux', ... u'Paris SG - Caen', u'Lyon - Nice']
```

Again, for the season 2014-2015, I will get twice the data regarding the main season's webpage (the first page):

```
[u'Bordeaux - Montpellier', u'Caen - Evian TG', ... , u'Toulouse - Nantes', u'Paris SG - Lille']

 [u'Bordeaux - Montpellier', u'Caen - Evian TG', ... , u'Toulouse - Nantes', u'Paris SG - Lille']
```

This issue doesn't arise when Selenium goes through the pages 2, 3, 4, ... of the season. Also, as you can see the list I'm iterating on doesn't have any doublons.  Finally, all the subsequent "sub-pages" seems to be getting iterated on fine.

What I'm doing wrong here?

I was thinking about adding waits, any suggestions apart from this?

The first detail worth noting is that I use the Firefox Webdriver. Also, I do the work on Jupyter notebooks (even when I restart and run all the issue is still here). Could those explain anything?

Cheers

EDIT

**Here is the code for extracting the tables' data. It returns a list of lists of data element which I unpack then and append to specific lists.**

```
def cells_data(table_soup):

    match_hour, teams, score, odd_home = [], [], [], []
    odd_draw, odd_away, odd_tot = [], [], []

    for tr in table_soup.find_all("tr"):
        for num, td in enumerate(tr.find_all("td")):
            if num == 0 and td.get_text() != u'':
                match_hour.append(td.get_text())

            elif num == 1 and td.get_text() != u'':
                teams.append(td.get_text())

            elif num == 2 and td.get_text() != u'':
                score.append(td.get_text())

            elif num == 3 and td.get_text() != u'':
                odd_home.append(td.get_text())

            elif num == 4 and td.get_text() != u'':
                odd_draw.append(td.get_text())

            elif num == 5 and td.get_text() != u'':
                odd_away.append(td.get_text())

            elif num == 6 and td.get_text() != u'' :
                odd_tot.append(td.get_text())

    return [match_hour, teams, score, odd_home, odd_draw, odd_away, odd_tot]
```

**Here is the code I use to go through the total list of links**

```
_match_hour, _teams, _score, _odd_home = [], [], [], []
_odd_draw, _odd_away, _odd_tot = [], [], []

for link in tot_links:

    browser.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

    table = soup.find("table", class_ = "table-main")
    match_hour, teams, score, odd_home, odd_draw, odd_away, odd_tot = cells_data(table)

    _match_hour.append(match_hour)
    _teams.append(teams)
    _score.append(score)
    _odd_home.append(odd_home)
    _odd_draw.append(odd_draw)
    _odd_away.append(odd_away)
    _odd_tot.append(odd_tot)

    print link
```

Comment: Not sure why would this be selenium related issue? Especially because you didn't provide any code you use for this.

Comment: @acikojevic I thought so mainly because I use selenium both to navigate through the pages and to allow me to muddle through javascript otherwise invisible with BSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

for anyone interested and passing by, the issue was my mismanagement of waits. Weirdly, it would end up in having the page getting parsed twice. Here I see that I didn't even put any.

In the end, as the page loads dynamically, I eventually added the following wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(parser.browser,100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located
                                                        ((By.CLASS_NAME,"table-main")))
```

It now works. And also I modified some bits of code, the major issue I was describing here was simply because of waits :)